# Writing a regular expression for fax numbers. Not the same as phone number

Tags: numbers, expression, fax

I need help writing a regular expression for a fax number. I need it to be option to have the country code. I need it to allow dashes in the country code.

Country code example:1-264
Fax Number with country code: 1-264 (555)-555-5555
Fax Number with country code: 1-264-(555)-555-5555
Fax Number with country code: 1-264-555-555-5555
either of these are allowed

I am using this in javascript but i just need the expression.

Current Code: ^(+\d{1,5}\s)?(?\d{3})?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: no this is for phone numbers. Country codes are longer and allow dashes in them